# How to disable certain cells or fix values in those cells based on the user input in another cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have four input cells - A4, B4, C4 and C6.

When a user will select 'Start 1-Period' or 'Start 2-Period' in cell C6 that means certain scripts will be running behind, then I need to disable cells or fix values of those cells in A4, B4, C4. You may say it as Non-editable.

When the scripts will stop running, then in cell C6 it will automatically goes back to 'Please select' option, then A4, B4, C4 cells should be editable.

Please check the image attached.[image: Goo]

Comment: I posted my answer. Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the cells should only be protected from edition while the script is running, and when that happens, the dropdown should be set to `Please Select`? Could you please share what you tried till now, including the code you're working on?

Comment: @lamblichus please check the post at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251082/facing-issues-while-executing-the-app-scripts-code-for-google-sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The process you are describing can be broken down into two parts:

1. You clearly need an *onEdit* trigger function that will change the protection status of the cells **A4:C4** according to **C1**.
2. You can control the value of **C1** according to your running scripts. For example, when your script is running, set the value of **C1** to *Start 1-Period* or *Start 2-Period*. Before the running script is finished, you can set the value of **C1** back to *Please Select*.

In this way, process 1. will be responsible for updating the protection status as soon as **C1** is edited and process 2. will be responsible for selecting the value of **C1** according to the scripts that are running behind.

---

**Explanation of the onEdit script:**

Every time you edit cell **C6** you apply protection rules to the range **A4:C4** according to the selected value. In more detail, every time you edit cell **C6** the script will initially remove all current protections. If the selected value of cell **C6** is changed to *Please Select* then no protection is applied. Otherwise, if the new value of **C6** is either *Start 1-Period* or *Start 2-Period* you apply protection to the range: **A4:C4**.

Here is the complete solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var sh_name = "Sheet1"; 
  var sh = e.source.getSheetByName(sh_name)
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if ( e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == sh_name && row==6 && col==3 ){

    var protections = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      var protection = protections[i];
      if (protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.remove();
      }
    }  
     var selection = sh.getRange('C6').getValue();
     var range = sh.getRange('A4:C4');

    if ( selection == 'Start 1-Period' || selection == 'Start 2-Period' ) {
      var protection = range.protect();} }
}
```

You just need to copy this code to the script editor, save the changes and then the script will take care of this process.

Note that my script applies to the sheet with name *Sheet1*. Change that part of the code if you work with a different sheet.

> **References**:

- [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
- [onEdit Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)