# Facing issues while executing the App Scripts code for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am facing few issues with the following scripts. Here the sheet name is 'Dashboard'. First paragraph under refreshSheet() is not working fine. The issues is:

The following code is producing two protections of A1:K4 each time I run the code (Dashboard!A1:K4 and Dashboard!A1:K4). Should do only one protection each time.

Please check the codes are as follows:

```
   function onEdit(e){  
      if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6' && e.range.getValue() === "Start 1-Period") {  
        refreshSheet();
        onePeriod();  
      }
      if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6' && e.range.getValue() === "Start 2-Period") {    
        refreshSheet();
        twoPeriod();  
      }   
    }
    
    function refreshSheet() {   
      //For protecting dashboard while scripts running
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
      var rangem = dashboard.getRange('A1:K4');   
      var protectionm = rangem.protect();
      var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
      protectionm.addEditor(me);
      protectionm.removeEditors(protectionm.getEditors());
      if (protectionm.canDomainEdit()) {
          protectionm.setDomainEdit(false);
      }
     
      // Other codes are here which are working fine        
    
      protectionm.remove();
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask you: 1. You say the code protects Dashboard!A1:K4 and Dashboard!A1:K4? So twice the same range> Or did you mean two different ranges. Also: does this behavior occur only when `refreshSheet()` is called `onEdit` or also when you run it manually?

Comment: Twice the same range Dashboard!A1:K4. This behavior occurs when refreshSheet() is called on onEdit(). I did not test it manually.

Comment: Please do. It is important to know either the problem is inside `refreshSheet()` itself or due to the fact that it is called twice (can happen for example if you have a simple and installable `onEdit` trigger installed simultaneously).

Comment: I am not sure how to test it manually. Please check the executions of two triggers I have for this spreadsheet at the attached image. Those are on Edit and on Change triggers for two different purpose.

Comment: Do you need the full code for refreshSheet() to check the issue?

Comment: Please also note that I have an On Edit trigger for onEdit() function.

Comment: If yo have an installed `onEdit` trigger, please rename the `onEdit` function - `onEdit` is a key word that binds to the function automatically a simple `onEdit` trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You have several triggers runnig simultaneously - this is the reason why `refreshSheet()` is running several times.

First of all:

**do NOT use the simple and installable `onEdit` trigger simultaneously - this leads to double execution and conflicts.**

- In your specific situation the simple `onEdit` trigger does not execute correctly (because it does not have the encessary permissions).
- You should however remove the simple trigger - this can be easily done by renaming `function onEdit(e)` to any other name that is not a reserved key word - e.g. `function Edit(e)`.
- You installable trigger will still run - since you manually bound it to the function.
- From your execution logs it seems that the installable `onChange trigger` runs at the same time like the `onEdit` trigger from which I can assume that you bound it to the same function - this makes your code execute twice.
- Instead, in case of implementing multiple triggers, you should bind each to a different function.
- From the code snippet you provided I cannot see your need to use an `onChange` trigger - maybe you it is a remainder from previous approaches.
- Please go on `Edit-> Current Projetc's triggers` , review all triggers you have installed, delete the unnecessary ones and make sure that the remaining ones are bound to different functions.

[image]

Second:

- To verify either the double execution of a code part is due to a double call of a function - test by running the funciton manually from the script editor.
- For this, simply chose the correct funciton from the dropdown menu (in your case - `refreshSheet()` and click on the run button (the triangle).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. For the last 36 hours I am trying to solve the issue. Posted in stackoverflow but no solution received. There is no problem with the code but it is the NAME of the Trigger issue you have rightly mentioned. I changed the onEdit() to classAttend() and the problem is solved. Excellent thinking.

Comment: could you please check my recent post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63743728/how-to-create-dynamic-map-or-links-using-range-of-latitude-and-longitude-values